# Как скрыть элемент через класс?

Tags: vue.js

столкнулся с проблемой, как скрыть/открыть элемент через класс внутри v-for

Вот код

```
<div class="trip" v-for="el in getEventsTrip">
    <div class="_plr-15 _fCSB" @click="el.isActive = !el.isActive">
      <h6 class="_19OSSB26Blue2 light">Trip {{el.id}}</h6>
      <p class="_16OSR24Blue2">
        {{moment(new Date()).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}}
        <span class="line">|</span>
        <span class="_16OSB24Blue2 light">20</span>
        km drove
      </p>

      <arrow-right
        fill-color="#566993"
        class="arrow-right"/>
    </div>


    <div :class="{ trip__footer: true, hidden: el.isActive}">
      <chart class="chart-container" :chartdata="chartData.data" :options="chartData.options"/>
    <button
      class="_fC _14OSR19Blue2 item">
      <p class="item__time">{{moment().tz('Europe/Minsk').format('LT')}} - {{moment().tz('Europe/Minsk').format('LT')}}</p>
      <div class="_fCC item__img-wrapper item__img-wrapper_custom">
        <slot/>
      </div>
      <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

А в чем собственно проблема?
Когда ваш `el.isActive = true` вы вешаете класс `hidden`

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

У каждого элемента он может быть, или не быть, а значит элемент либо скрыт, либо нет